# Bind unix program to different interface

Tags: linux, networking

Is it possible to move an active program comms from one interface to other.

Example:
If program1 is communicating on interface eth0, is there any command to move communication of program1 to wlan0. Without stopping it, or disabling eth0?

Sorry for the vague question!

Comment: Most programs communicate with IP adresses and leave the choice of interface to the kernel. The programs that do use interfaces rarely do so to communicate, but rather to monitor something on that interface, but they use different options to do so. So at current the best advice we can give is RTFM, or improve your question e.g. with mention of which program we're talking about and why you think you have to tell it to communicate o a particular interface.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about your environment, program, client, system types, network and the rest, we can give only global ideas that you might explore. But a possible set-up would be:

- put an alias on eth0
- let the other party communicate with the alias
- after some time, remove the alias from eth0 with `ifconfig eth0:0 down`
- apply the alias to wlan0

Eth0 will remain active this way. Of course, you need to look at the rest of the network. There may be issues with ARP-caching, subnetting et cetera et cetera.

You may even look at altering the MAC-ids of the interfaces to a 'service-MAC'.